# Java In-Application Storage from Xml Data

Tags: java, xml, storage

Hi I am developing a game in Java for learning purposes and have a question regarding in-app handling of data

Say I have a bunch of xml files storing a variety of statistics for, weapons armours etc and I parse these files into my application as lists;

Note, this data will never change and is effectively "final", it is constant data that will be used by the game.

Now my question is, would you store this data (for use while the game is running) in a class (in my example here a singleton) within your application that you can access easily? So for example something like this (where the list has been read elsewhere by the XML parser)

```
public class WeaponData {

   private List<Weapon> weaponData;

   public static final WeaponData instance = new WeaponData(parseXml("weapons"));


   private WeaponData(List<Weapon> data) {
       weaponData = data;
   }

   public static WeaponData getInstance() {
       return instance;
   }

   public List<Weapon> getWeaponData() {
       return weaponData;
   }
}
```

And allows me to use the data with

```
WeaponData.getInstance().getWeaponData();
```

If so, is this the way to go about it, or is there a better way?

Or, the only alternative I can think of, is to keep reading the XML whenever its needed (which seems unwise, paticularly given, this data retrieval may (for a commercial application atleast) be a network operation, even if in my case it is just a hdd read). Plus if anything else it would be repeated code.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Can you give me an overview of how big is the XML, because for small XMLs it's a lot of work to saved them in a DB and the gain is not so much, you can cache the value in disk, but you will add complexity, that's why for me is important to know what's the size of the XML file. If we're talking of Kbs I will suggest to leave it as it is.

Comment: Note that``final`` is only about the reference itself. The invocation of methods on an object stored in a ``final`` variable has nothing to do with the semantics of ``final``. So, in your above example, someone could change the contents of ``List<Weapon> weaponData`` after its creation

Comment: Well, I am not talking about DBs at all. I think you misunderstood, I have some xml files they are all currently a few kbs, I doubt they will ever exceed 500kbs or so. But I just want to know essentially how you would make this data available (potentially multiple times) within the application.

Comment: @Keith, I know, just couldnt be bothered to get into immutable collections for the sake of this question (not what I want to know). But thanks anyway! Would create a Wrapper around the collection to make it immutable when  Iactually implement it. Or Collections.unmodifiableList etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably read it in once and save it, but don't store it as a singleton.  Read the WeaponData during initialization and store an instance of it.  If you don't like that you are welcome to use the pattern you suggested, it just might be awkward later.

If you ever get to where WeaponData might be updated while the app is running, you may want to re-read it, but not ever time.

Comment: Sorry about all the edits on that answer--I re-read the question and found that I read it completely wrong the first time.

Comment: Ok, so on the whole I am on the right tracks with what I am trying to do by the sound of it, I guess the awkwardness will be a good learning curve if/when (probably when) I encounter it.
Edit: Its ok, was a fairly tough question to word I suppose, so it may have been slightly hard to understand

Comment: Absolutely, just keep an eye out for it :)  (Awesome attitude about doing it the way you are and then learning, by the way)

Comment: @BillK What did you mean by  "store" an instance of it?

Comment: @Keith Well, if you use getInstance() in the middle of a method... how do you test it with a mock version of that object?  Better to pass it in.  This means you need to keep an instance of that object somewhere in a class that always has an active instance--like your main frame or some other object that your event can access and pass it down to the method that needs it.  When this becomes too awkward (Passing around too many objects), Dependency Injection is the pattern that is generally used to simplify things.

Comment: Gotcha. I didn't interpret your message such that "store" meant  "class variable".  And yes, dependency injection would be my approach, too, though as you implied, it seems to be too much a departure to directly asked his question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking that your approach will work, especially as you have mentioned that the data won't become large enough that it imposes on memory. Another concern would be the frequency in which you must read the data. There's a tradeoff between those two considerations, but it sounds like the small XML size warrants unmarshalling the XML into objects immediately.

Just for completeness, you should be using [JAX-B](https://jaxb.java.net/) to generate Java classes from your XML schema, rather than rolling your own parser.

If you fear that the XML's data may change, you might consider using the [`WatchService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/WatchService.html) API to detect changes and re-parse the XML file.

Comment: Aye, JAXB indeed, however I did not mention in my question that it is for Android, and JAXB is not included in Android (and would I believe add to the size of my apk significantly if I added it). Could have used something like SimpleXml tho, but as it is for learning, why not parse the XML myself while I am at it. You are also right above that I should use dependency injection. But I believe using it adds a layer of complexity (to implement), paticularly in Android that I wish to save for my second "learning" application. I believe Dagger works fairly well with Android